# Angularjs Factoryname.function is not a function

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory

I am trying to call a factory function from the controller .

My code:

```
angular.module("mainApp", ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'toaster'])

.factory("authenticationSvc", function($http, $q, $window) {
    var userInfo;

    function login(userName, password) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post("/api/login", {
            userName: userName,
            password: password
        }).then(function(result) {
            userInfo = {
                accessToken: result.data.access_token,
                userName: result.data.userName
            };
            $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(userInfo);
            deferred.resolve(userInfo);
        }, function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
        login: login
    };
})
.controller("LoginController", function($scope, toaster, $rootScope, $stateParams, $location, $http, authenticationSvc) {
    $scope.login = authenticationSvc.login();
});
```

But I am getting an error

> TypeError: authenticationSvc.login is not a function

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to $scope.login = ...?
What value das authenticationSvc have?

Answer (score 0):

Here below is the basic example that how factories are behaving. Please change your code with below one

```
angular.module("mainApp", ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'toaster'])

.factory("authenticationSvc", function($http, $q, $window) {
    var userInfo, authentication = {};

    authentication.login = function(userName, password) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post("/api/login", {
            userName: userName,
            password: password
        }).then(function(result) {
            userInfo = {
                accessToken: result.data.access_token,
                userName: result.data.userName
            };
            $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(userInfo);
            deferred.resolve(userInfo);
        }, function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    return authentication;
})
.controller("LoginController", function($scope, toaster, $rootScope, $stateParams, $location, $http, authenticationSvc) {
    $scope.login = authenticationSvc.login(user,password);
});
```

Please check though I didn't test it. Inside in your **factory** :

> You just create an object, add properties to it, then return that same
>   object. When you pass this service into your controller, those
>   properties on the object will now be available in that controller
>   through your factory.

Answer (score 0):

The function login needs two parameter

So the function login without a parameter isn't definded

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the approach and formalization of factory is not done properly.

try using the following approach..

```
.factory("authenticationSvc", function($http, $q, $window) {
var userInfo;

var authenticationSvc={};

//Define login()
authenticationSvc.login=function(userName, password) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post("/api/login", {
        userName: userName,
        password: password
    }).then(function(result) {
        userInfo = {
            accessToken: result.data.access_token,
            userName: result.data.userName
        };
        $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(userInfo);
        deferred.resolve(userInfo);
    }, function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

//return Factory Object
return authenticationSvc;

})
```

And in the controller , try calling in the same approach

```
.controller("LoginController", function($scope, toaster, $rootScope, $stateParams, $location, $http, authenticationSvc) {
$scope.login = authenticationSvc.login();
```

});

Hope this helps.
Cheers